# How to get the name of the file of a particular type in a directory?

Tags: directory, filenames, nsis

I have a string variable name in `$1` which is a path (a directory). I need to copy a file from my output directory to `$1` during installation. So I do like this:

```
SetOutPath $1
File "Database\*.xxx"
```

That is from `Database` folder to `$1` all files of type `.xxx`. But I have only one file of that type. How do I get the name of that file in another variable?

Eg, my `Database` folder would look like:

```
Database -> 224eadf234.xxx
```

I don't want to hardcode the base name `224eadf234.xxx` in the nsis script since it can be something else in the future, but the extension is going to be `.xxx` always. That's why I go for `*.xxx` approach. But I do need to get the name of the file during run time. Since there is only such file in the directory `Database` I assume its going to be easy.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
!appendfile "$%temp%\tmp1234.xxx" "This is a test" ; Create dummy file

; Find file at compile-time (on Windows)
!tempfile NSH
!system 'for %A IN ("$%temp%\*.xxx") DO echo !define THEFILE "%~A" > "${NSH}"'
!include "${NSH}"
!delfile "${NSH}"
!undef NSH
!error "FILE=${THEFILE}"

Section
!include LogicLib.nsh
StrCpy $1 $instdir\test
SetOutPath $1
File "$%temp%\*.xxx"

; Find file at run-time
FindFirst $2 $3 "$1\*.xxx"
${If} $3 != ""
    DetailPrint "First *.xxx file = $3"
${EndIf}
FindClose $2
SectionEnd
```